# Display text in textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have used the following code in **index.jsp** to set the value of textarea INPUT_TEXT and INPUT_TEXT2 in a form after extensive processing, wherein the text goes through a servlet, a java class and the preprocessed data then gets returned to the 2nd textarea.

CODE I:

```
<td>
<% 
   String txtvalue="";
   if(request.getAttribute("x")!=null){
       txtvalue=request.getAttribute("x").toString();
       System.out.println("txtvalue= "+txtvalue);
 }%>

 <textarea id="INPUT_TEXT" name="INPUT_TEXT" style="font-size: 13pt;" rows="15" cols="50"><%=txtvalue%></textarea>
</td>

<td>
<% 
    String txt="";
    if(request.getAttribute("y")!=null){
       txt=request.getAttribute("y").toString();
       System.out.println("txt= "+txt);
 }%>

 <textarea id="INPUT_TEXT2" name="INPUT_TEXT2" style="font-size: 13pt;" rows="15" cols="50"><%=txt%></textarea>
 </td>
```

I have tried using

1)**innerHTML**,

2)setting the value using document.getElementById("INPUT_TEXT") and

3)the present method which I have given in the code I.

Unfortunately, nothing works!

**Method 3 (code I) used to work**, but then I had to make some changes in the function that is called after onclick, to make a POST request, which now looks like this:

CODE II

```
function submitPreprocessForm() {
   var postData=$("#maryWebClient").serializeArray();
   $.ajax({
     url: "preprocess",
     context:this,
     type:"POST",
     dataType:"JSON",
     data:postData,
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
     success: function(response){
     }
 });
}
```

Now, the txt and txtvalue (Code I) are being printed **only to the NetBeans output console** (correctly, I might add) **but not to the webpage**, which gets reset when I click the submit button. Thus, although the entire internal functioning works perfectly, the only problem is text not being displayed in the respective textareas.
Kindly help.

Comment: What are you getting in `response` ? show the result of `console.log(response)`

Comment: You could try ` <textarea id="INPUT_TEXT" name="INPUT_TEXT" style="font-size: 13pt;" rows="15" cols="50" value=<%=txtvalue%> ></textarea>`. The value in textarea you get it by getting a reference to the input field in an element and then call element.value. You can get it or set it.

Comment: No, you can not set value as attribute in `textarea`. You need to write the HTML inside the `textarea` tags.

Comment: 'response' is not needed. NetBeans shows it as "unused" and on removing it, the code works normally.

Comment: @Vineet could you be a bit more specific please?

Comment: @Ovidiu I tried this as mentioned in the method 2), but it did not work.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to populate the textfield from the value received from the execution of the function submitPreprocessForm

Then why not use JavaScript in the success handler:
`success: function(response){
     }`

Comment: What would go inside this handler?

Comment: something like this:
`function(response)
{
var myTextArea = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
myTextArea.innerText = 'SOME_TEXT_PARSED_FROM_response';
}`

Comment: @shariqkhan Unfortunately, that is also not working. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach solved my problem and text is displayed in the textrea.

```
success: function(response){
             $("#INPUT_TEXT").val(response["x"]);
             $("#INPUT_TEXT2").val(response["y"]);
         },
```

I had to remove the `<%=txtvalue%>` as it caused the textarea to be initialized to null.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <textarea id="text" ></textarea>
    <button type="submit" onclick="show()"> submit</button>
</div>
```

```
function show(){
     let a = document.getElementById("text");
     console.log(a.value);
}
```

The above JS function show() , shows the content in textarea after clicking the submit button .